# Showing that an algebraic lattice is a lattice.

Tags: lattice-orders

> Let $(L, \wedge, \vee)$ be an algebraic lattice. If we define
> \begin{equation*}
>  x \le y :\iff   x \wedge y = x
> \end{equation*}
> then $(L,\le)$ is a lattice ordered set.

This is what I have to prove (without using duality). First I showed that $(L,\le)$ is a poset proving partial order relations. Then I showed that $\sup L=x\vee y$. But I am not able to show that $\inf L=x\wedge y$ as the relation defined in the question is for $\wedge$.

So if I want to show that $\inf L=x\wedge y$, firstly I need to show that it is a lower bound. For that, I should use Absorptive laws: $x\vee(x\wedge y)=x\not\implies x\ge x\wedge y$ and  $y\vee(y\wedge x)=y\not\implies y\ge (y\wedge x)=(x\wedge y)$ which shows nothing for $(x\wedge y)$ to be a lower bound for the pair $x,y\in L$. Which argument can I use? Because the condition says that $x\le y\iff x\wedge y=x$. Can I redefine the condition as $y\ge x\iff y\vee x=y$ (something like this)?

Answer (score 2):

You can deduce $x \leq y \iff x \lor y = y$ as follows:

\begin{align*}
  x \leq y &\Rightarrow x \land y = x  \\
           &\Rightarrow (x \land y) \lor y = x \lor y &&\text{ we just join $y$ at both sides}\\
           &\Rightarrow y = x \lor y &&\text{ by absorption law}
\end{align*}

In the other direction:

\begin{align*}
 y = x \lor y &\Rightarrow y \land x = (x \lor y) \land x \\
              &\Rightarrow y \land x = x \\
              &\Rightarrow y \geq x
\end{align*}
Using again just absorption and the definition given by the question.
The rest, as you already noticed, should follow from that.

edit: correction pointed out in the comments.

Comment: You are right. My mistake.

Comment: can't we just join $y$ from both sides?

Comment: But this was not my question. My question was how I show that $x\wedge y$ is a lower bound.

Comment: Well, you asked if you could re-define $x \leq y \iff x \lor y = y$.  I assumed by your phrasing you knew how to go from there to solve your question.

Comment: actually there are multiple questions. As I mentioned in my question that the defining operator is $\wedge$. With this, how can I show $\wedge$ is lower bound? Though +1 for your answer.

Comment: $(x \land y) \land y = x \land (y \land y) = x \land y$ by associativity. Then by your definition $x \land y \leq y$. Same for $x$. Then $x \land y$ is a lower bound.

Comment: Ahhh!! So associativity played role here. These seem so easy after knowing the answer. But too brainstorming!!!